# getSupportActionBar() is not supporting in fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to change the actionbar Background colour in fragment and i am using

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

to change the colour but in fragment
 `getSupportActionBar()`
 is not resolve for me`

Comment: *getSupportActionBar() is not resolve for me* because use `getSupportActionBar()` is method of an activity u need to use `getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);`

Answer (score 0):

You must need something like this:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSupportActionBar` needs to be accessible from your activity. To access it from a fragment, you can do something like this:

```
private Context _context;

...

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    _context = context;
}

...

((AppCompatActivity)_context).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

It's good practise to get the `Context` from onAttach, since calling `getContext()` or `getActivity()` later on can result in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have implemented the support  dependencies

In the build.gradle(module level, not the app level)  under dependencies check if you have the correct ones:

```
   //Verify the version is matching your other  support dependency versions 
 implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
```

And then you can access in the fragment by this example:

```
private ActionBar supportActionBar;
...
//inside on attach
supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

also make sure you have imported the right  SupportActionBar